# Access Shell - not getting closed

Tags: vba, excel

I am using vba in excel to get/write from an access db.

I am declaring objects and setting them values in the beginning of the program. There is also a piece of code in the end, that closes the connection. But the access shell still appears.

Here is a copy of the code,

```
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Dim objAccess               As Object
Dim db                      As Object
Dim qdef                    As Object

' OPEN ACCESS APPLICATION
    Set objAccess = CreateObject("Access.Application")
    objAccess.OpenCurrentDatabase DatabasePath

 ' OPEN INTERNAL DATABASE
    Set db = objAccess.Currentdb


    ' Some Operations I am performing with rs(recordsets)

    'Setting the Created Objects to nothing
    Set qdef = Nothing
    Set db = Nothing
    Set objAccess = Nothing


ValidationForm.Hide


Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
```

Comment: Try `objAccess.Quit` before setting it to `Nothing`.

Comment: Why not just use ADO/OLEDB or something similar to talk to the database instead of loading the entire Access engine?

Comment: @braX that's a very, very good question!

Comment: @braX I read the Internet and I think ADO/OLEDB is the way to go. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ```
> Set objAccess = Nothing
> ```

This releases the reference you're holding to the `Access.Application` object: it doesn't do anything other than that.

And because that object has a ton of other references to it (within itself), releasing *your* reference won't make a difference - the refcount isn't zero, thus the object still exists.

Calling `objAccess.Quit` would instruct the object to release its stuff and clean up whatever was left behind, like that `db` reference that wasn't `Close`d.

That said, consider using an ADODB connection instead of loading the entire Access application and object model.